# Unable to derive an expression in study of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

While self studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman and Kunze I am unable to derive this following expression.

[image]

> My question is in 5 th line after the underlined line in blue ie the line " The only terms which survive in this huge sum are the terms where q=r } ",Not anything after  it.

> I think we should add condition i=s ,along with
> condition q=r  .

This i =s appeared due to solving $E^{r, s}  ( \alpha_{i} ) $as due to solving $  E^{r, s}  $ I got $ \delta_{i s} $ × $\beta_{r} $  and then again solving the condition we get q=r.

Here I am using result used in theorem 5( page 76) which is $E^{p, q} (\alpha_{i} )$  = 0 if i$\neq$ q and $\beta_{p} $ if i=q.

Kindly guide what should be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E^{p,q}$ takes the $q$th $\alpha$-vector to the $p$th, and sends all others to zero. It's nice to look at this in the case where the $\alpha$-vectors are just the standard basis vectors, so that
$$
\alpha_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\ 0\\ \vdots \\0},
\alpha_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\ 0 \\\vdots \\0},
\ldots,
\alpha_n = \pmatrix{0\\0\\ 0 \\\vdots \\1},
$$
for in that case, the matrix for $E^{p,q}$ is all zeroes, except for a $1$ in row $p$, column $q$. If you multiply this by $E^{a,b}$ on the right, it's clear that you get all zeroes *unless* some column of $E^{a,b}$ contains a "1" in column $q$. But the **only** $1$ in $E^{a,b}$ is in column $b$. So you need $q = b$. And you end up taking $\alpha_a$ to $\alpha_b = \alpha_q$, which is then transformed, but $E^{p,q}$, to $\alpha_p$, so you've got $E^{a,p}$ as a result.

Comment: Can you also take a look at the question asked by me if you have some spare time . I shall be really thankful to you . This question hasnot been answered completely . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743685/prove-w-w00-where-w00-is-annihilator-of-w0