# Prove $W= (W^{0})^{0} $ (where $(W^{0})^{0} $ is annihilator of $W^0$)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This question was asked in my Linear Algebra quiz yesterday and I could not solve it.

> Edit : V is a finite dimensional vector space and W is a subspace of V.

> Question: Prove that $W= {(W^{0})^0} $

Definition of $W^{0} = \{ f \text{ belonging to } V^{*} \mid f(\alpha) =0 , \ \alpha \text{ belongs to } W\}$.

But the problem occurs in the definition of annihilator of $W^{0}$.

> How should annihilator of $W^{0} $ be defined?

> How should I prove the asked result?

> There is another subsequent question which I am asking here as it's related: Why $W$ is always a subspace of $W^{00}$?

Kindly guide.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but $(W^{0})^{0}$ isnt the annihilator of $W$ but rather, the annihilator of the annihilator of $W.$

Comment: What are the assumptions on $W$? In particular, is it assumed to be a subspace of $V$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Can you please tell me the reasoning why W must always be a subset of $W^{00} $ ? I shall be really thankful to you for your help!!

Comment: I can't answer your question until you answer mine. You introduce $W$ and $V^*$ without giving any hint as to what you mean by these symbols, or how they relate to each other. Come on, meet us halfway!

Comment: I guess you don't really want an answer to your question.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I am sorry , I was busy in an important work and hence could not use the site. But I really want answer to my question and understand the reasoning behind it. I should have added  more details and I beg your pardon for that . I am adding all relevant details.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I have edited it. Kindly help me if you have some spare time.

Comment: No time now, maybe tomorrow. Meanwhile, are you sure that nowhere in Hoffman and Kunze is there any discussion of identifying $V$ with $V^{**}$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I couldn't find it. I have read all of Chapter 3 .

Comment: @GerryMyerson do you have any spare time now for my question ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on vacation.

Comment: @Ben I have edited my answer to include more arguments.

Comment: We can explain why $W$ is always a subspace of $W^{00}$ as follows. Let $V$ be a vector space over a filed $\Bbb F$ (for instance, $\Bbb F=\Bbb R$) and $V^*$ be the linear space of all linear functionals from $V$ to $\Bbb F$. Let $W$ and $W^*$ be any subspaces of $V$ and $V^*$, respectively. The definitions of the their annihilator or $W^0$ and $W^{*0}$, respectively, are dual. Namely, $$W^{0} = \{ x^*\in V^{*}: \forall x\in W (x^*(x)=0)\},$$ $$W^{*0} = \{ x\in V: \forall x^*\in W^* (x^*(x)=0)\}.$$ Now let $x\in W$ be any element. Since $x^*(x)=0$ for each $x^*\in W^0$, $x\in W^{00}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the question is missing the assumptions $W$ is a subspace and $V$ is finite-dimensional, hence I am going to assume them.

Note that by definition $W^{00}:=(W^{0})^{0}=\{\phi \in V^{**}: \phi(f)=0 \text{ for all } f \in W^0\}.$

We have $$\begin{align*}\dim W+\dim W^0&=\dim V\end{align*}\\
\dim W^0+\dim W^{00}=\dim V^*.$$ Using $\dim V=\dim V^*,$ we obtain $$\dim W=\dim W^{00}$$ but $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$ and so $W=W^{00}.$

**Edit 1:** To see that $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00},$ show that $W \subseteq W^{00}$ by identifying $V^{**}$ with $V.$

**Edit 2:** In order to show $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$, one needs to identify $V^{**}$ with $V$ as follows:

Let $x\in V$ and define $L_x:V^* \to F$ (field) by $L_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f \in V^*$. Then one can show that $x \mapsto L_x$ is an isomorphism from $V$ onto $V^{**}$ (Theorem 3.6.17 in Hoffman and Kunze, 2nd edition). Therefore for any $x \in V$, the element $L_x$ is its representative in $V^{**}$. Thus to show $W \subseteq W^{00}$, it suffices to show that for any $x \in W$, one has $L_x \in W^{00}$. To this end, let $x \in W$. Then for every $f \in W^0$, we have $L_x(f)=f(x)=0$. This shows that $L_x \in W^{00}$. It follows that $W \subseteq W^{00}$. Moreoever $W$ is a vector space itself and hence $W$ is a subspace of $W^{00}$.

Comment: I am not able to understand how W is a subset of $W^{00} $ ? Can you please tell in a bit detail?

Comment: Identifying $V$ with $V^{**}.$

Comment: how would you identify $V^{**} $  with V ? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You can see any standard texts on Linear algebra. For example Theorem 17 in Chapter in Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze. The whole section is useful to read, in fact.

Comment: I have been following Hoffman Kunze but this is not answered there on Page 108-109 . Can you kindly give reason ? is it a lenghty deduction?

Comment: Maybe we have different editions but I'm referring to Section 3.6. In the 2nd edition, Theorem 17 is on Page 107.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading Hoffman and Kunze these days. This confusion got me. Thus, I come to StackExchange for help as usual.

Technically, $(W^0)^0$ is a subspace of $V^{**}$, which is a vector space of linear functionals. Since $V$ is a general vector space, how the heck can a general subspace equal to a subspace of linear functionals? Hoffman and Kunze (2nd Edition) give an explanation on page 108 (the paragraph above Theorem 18).

I think, it is all about definition. Since $V$ and $V^{**}$ are isomorphic, the authors implicitly define $(W^0)^0$ as a subspace of $V$, which is $\{\alpha\in V: f(\alpha)=0\;\forall f\in W^0\}$. If you got this definition, you got $W\subseteq (W^0)^0$ right away.